# Admin session time out issue in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, session, logout

Admin Config settings:
System => Configuration =>Web => Session Cookie Management => set Cookie Lifetime 259200.
And

> Go to =>  **System => Configuration => Admin => Security => set
>   Session Lifetime = 259200 (seconds)**

**Clean** the magento cache.

And made changes to **php.ini**:

```
session.cookie_lifetime 259200

session.gc_maxlifetime 259200
```

after all these things admin logged out inactivity of 15 mins.